# Mongodb java driver slow performance

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a project which implement as front : VUE.JS and back : Java servlet (tomcat). My servlet perform request on a mongoDB database with thousands products. (*I am new with mongodb query*).

**The problem for me is that my servlet take many time to respond with a data array.**

I need advice to speed up my query and speed up my servlet process to send data to the front.

1. First I would like to know if in mongodb, is it efficient to use query like this (this is an example of query with many lookup, because I have to fetch data from many collections) :

   ```
   db.getCollection('collection_name').aggregate([
      {
         "$match":{
            "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
         }
      },
      {
         "$lookup":{
            "from":"collection_name",
            "localField":"id",
            "foreignField":"id",
            "as":"trans"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$trans"
      },
      {
         "$lookup":{
            "from":"collection_name",
            "localField":"trans.id",
            "foreignField":"trans_id",
            "as":"orders"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$orders"
      },
      {
         "$match":{
            "$and":[
               {
                  "orders.status":"status_state"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$orders.products"
      },
      {
         "$lookup":{
            "from":"collection_name",
            "localField":"orders.products.id",
            "foreignField":"id",
            "as":"detailsProducts"
         }
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$detailsProducts"
      },
      {
         "$unwind":"$detailsProducts.products"
      },
      {
         "$project":{
            "_id":1,
            "orders":1,
            "detailsProducts": 1
         }
      }
   ])
   ```
2. In second as I say, my java servlet take many time to perform datas treatment, after definding my aggregate i perform a loop operation to push data into a json array like this :

   ```
   // Define json array
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

   // Get collection
   AggregateIterable<Document> myCollection = 
       MongoDB.getCollection("coll_name").aggregate(...);

   // Going through all documents (thousands of document)
   for (Document orderDocument : orderCollection) {
     // Get all products and they references
     arrays.put(new JSONObject(orderDocument.toJson()));
   }

   // AFTER THE END OF LOOP, MY SERVLET SEND THE ARRAY TO THE FRONT
   ```

**Note :** I work with mongodb java driver 3.5 (i try both : core driver and async drive)

I would like to get some advise to speed up my treatment and optimize my request.

Comment: You're asking about the performance of the java driver rather than Mongo itself? Do you get satisfactory performance if you execute the query directly in Mongo?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I get statisfactory performance when I execute my query directly in Mongo or RoboMongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a `JSONArray` with thousands of elements is not going to scale very well. You're better off streaming your JSON directly back to the client. So, assuming this returns in reasonable time:

```
// Get collection
AggregateIterable<Document> myCollection =
    MongoDB.getCollection("coll_name").aggregate(...);
```

then something like the following should improve things considerably:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.Encoder;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.json.JsonWriter;
...
public void writeAsJsonTo(AggregateIterable<Document> orderCollection,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    final Encoder<Document> encoder = new DocumentCodec();
    final JsonWriter jsonWriter =
        new JsonWriter(httpServletResponse.getWriter());
    final EncoderContext encoderContext = EncoderContext.builder()
        .isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build();

    jsonWriter.writeStartDocument();
    jsonWriter.writeStartArray("orders");
    // Going through all documents (thousands of document)
    for (Document orderDocument : orderCollection) {
        encoder.encode(jsonWriter, orderDocument, encoderContext);
    }
    jsonWriter.writeEndArray();
    jsonWriter.writeEndDocument();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very helpfull. My treatment is now faster. I will see the full result when my app will run on the production environnment with many, many, many data.